# tinymce suddenly stops working when I add the css loader in webpack config

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, tinymce

I start my application by cloning code from https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap

This project use webpack and npm.

I want to use select2 so I did `npm install select 2` in its `lib/assets` directory

I want to add a multi select search field to my project details page (which is `app/views/plans/_edit_details.html.erb`), so I added code like this:

```
      <%= f.select(:my_options,
         options_for_select({first_option: '123'}, ['123']),
         {},
         { id: 'select-field',
           class: 'form-control',
           multiple: 'multiple' }) %>
```

and added these to its corresponding JavaScript file (which is `lib/assets/javascripts/views/plans/edit_details.js`):

```
  // Set up Select2 for the multi select search field
  $('#select-field').select2({
    placeholder: 'Please enter text',
  });
```

and also these because webpack need to know the code I need:

```
import 'select2/dist/js/select2';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';
```

This project only use sass? so I added the css loader in the webpack config (`lib/assets/webpack.config.js`):

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015'],
    },
  },
  // above is old code, below is new code
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  },
```

Now (After the moment where I added the new css loader), the multi select search works, but the tinymce text area box in the application suddenly doesn't work anymore.

I don't know why this happen and don't know where to start debugging this. Where have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in `app/views/plans/_edit_details.html.erb` file, I need to add these 2 lines:

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete';
import 'select2';
```

instead of:

```
import 'select2/dist/js/select2';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';
```